# send an email to the user in APEX

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a region in a page where the text gets populated via a pl/sql. I have a copy button in that page which has a dynamic action to copy the content to a clipboard. Now I want this content to be emailed. what should be my approach.

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of copying the content to the clipboard, you could do the following:

- Create a page item to hold the text in the region
- Create a button to Submit the page
- Create a page process of type "send email" to send the value of the page item with condition of when-button-pressed